# pinterest v3 api exchange auth code for access token : invalid_grant

Tags: pinterest

Using v3 Pinterest Analytics API

Trying to exchange an authorization code for an access token and I'm getting the following error:

```
{"error":{"message":"None","oauth_error_code":"invalid_grant"},"code":283,"data":null,"message":"The authorization grant is invalid","endpoint_name":"oauth_access_token","status":"failure"}
```

In following these instructions:

```
https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/redoc/#section/User-Authorization/Exchange-the-code-for-an-access-token
```

I successfully obtained an authorization code. Now I want to exchange it for an access_token. I submit the following curl:

```
curl -X PUT \
--url https://api.pinterest.com/v3/oauth/access_token/ \
--data "code=1234authcode&redirect_uri=https://myURL.com/&grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=123appId&client_secret=123secret"
```

The redirect_uri is the same as that which was registered. The app secret and app Id are accurate as per this notification we received today:

```
Your App ID has been enabled. You can now see your app secret in our Developer App Portal and start building.
```

I have tried various incarnations of the curl thinking I've botched the args I'm passing in and that's still a possibility, so any help there would be appreciated, however, I'm wondering if my app Id and secret are bad or truly invalid somehow. We've only just received them. Any ideas or theories welcome.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to answer my own question, but it turns out that the auth code was bad. After fetching a new authorization code I was able to obtain an access_token using the approach shown above. What was initially confusing is that I literally got the original auth code moments before using it so I didn't doubt it's validity as much as I should have I guess.

Comment: Any more details on this? Is there a timeout on the auth code then?